# ValueError: Saving saving in appending mode in Pytables

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, hdf5, pytables

I have 100 images, each of `85*85 size` (`width*height`), given by numpy array (`data`) as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import tables as tb


data = np.random.rand(100, 85, 85)
print (data.shape)
```

I want to save every image into a h5 file one by one in an appending mode.

```
fo = "data.h5"

h5 = tb.open_file(fo, mode='w')

group = h5.create_group(h5.root, 'data')

atom = tb.Float64Atom()

ds = h5.create_earray(group, 'test', atom,
                       (0, data.shape[1], data.shape[2]))

for ix in range(data.shape[0]):
    dd = data[ix, :, :]
       
    ds.append(dd)

ds.flush()
ds.close()
```

However, I got following error:

ValueError: the ranks of the appended object (2) and the `/data/test` EArray (3) differ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with your syntax when accessing the `data` array elements. When you use `dd = data[ix, :, :]`, the `dd.shape=(85, 85)` You need `dd = data[ix:ix+1, :, :]` to get a 1 row.

Loading data row-by-row is not efficient if you have to append a lot of rows. Better to put them in an array and append the entire array. This is shown in the creation of `ds2.append(data)`

Here is the updated solution. Note, I prefer `with/as` to open files for cleaner file error handling.

```
with tb.open_file(fo, mode='w') as h5:
    group = h5.create_group(h5.root, 'data')
    atom = tb.Float64Atom() 
    ds = h5.create_earray(group, 'test', atom,
                         (0, data.shape[1], data.shape[2]))
    for ix in range(data.shape[0]):
        dd = data[ix:ix+1, :, :]
        print (dd.shape)   
        ds.append(dd)

# Method to create Earray with parent groups, 
# then append all image data at one time
    ds2 = h5.create_earray('/data2', 'test2', atom,
                     (0, data.shape[1], data.shape[2]),
                     createparents=True)
    ds2.append(data)
```

If you want to load all of the data in 1 Earray, it is simple to load using the `obj=data` parameter referencing your array. This retains the shape definition expandable in dimension 0.  See modified code below.

```
h5 = tb.open_file(fo, mode='w')
group = h5.create_group(h5.root, 'data')
ds = h5.create_earray('/data', 'test', atom,
                     (0, data.shape[1], data.shape[2]),
                     obj=data)
ds.flush() # not necessary
ds.close() # not necessary
h5.close() ## REQUIRED!!!!
```

Comment: I knew obj method but I want to implement it in the appending mode. I really want to expand the array through for loop.

Comment: OK, see new example. Old method left for  reference.